# Does exists a function that has the following o-notation properties?

Tags: limits

Let $p>0$ be any real positive. Does there exist a function $f(x)$ which is $o(|x|^p)$ in $x=0$ yet not $O(|x|^{p+\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(0) = 0$ and on $[1/2^n, 1/2^n-1[$, $f(x)=x^{p+1/\sqrt{n}}$

The idea is to have something like $f(x) = x^{p+\alpha}$ with alpha smaller than epsilon for any $\varepsilon$ when $x \to 0$.

Or $f(x) = x^{p-log(x)}$

Comment: Understood the idea but everything I tried made it not o(|x|^p)

Comment: Like your example: f(x)/|x|^p = |x|^|x|^2->1

Comment: ok, the previous one worked, I thought that p+x^2 was cleaner but didnt check it, reverting to first answer

Comment: What about: f(x)=|x|^(p+1/sqrt(-ln(|x|))) ? Checking it now

Comment: yeah, this is a cleaner version of the [1/2^n...] thing

Comment: Cool, that works.